Using conformal mapping to solve Laplace equation
Given the circles $$C_1 : x^2 + y^2 = 1,\quad C_2 : 5x^2 - 4x + 5y^2 = 0$$ let $D$ be the finite region between $C_1$ and $C_2$. Using the conformal mapping $$w = \frac{z-2}{2z-1}$$ solve the problem $$\nabla^2 \phi = 0 \text{ in D }, \quad \phi = 1 \text{ on }C_1, \quad \phi = 2 \text{ on }C_2$$
I have shown that the mapping given takes $D$ to the new region $A = \{z: 1 < |z| < 2\}$, so we are left with the problem of solving the Laplace equation on an annulus. Working in polar coordinates, I know that the solution to this problem takes the form $$\Phi(r) = A + B\log r$$ with $$\Phi(1) = 1, \quad \Phi(2) = 2$$However, I would ideally like to stay working in $\mathbb{C}$ as otherwise I am confused on how I could reverse my transformation, giving a solution to the original problem. How can I go about solving the remainder of this problem? Any help would be appreciated.
